# Laravel postgresql join error. "Operator does not exist"

Tags: laravel, postgresql, laravel-5.6

My laravel query code

```
$query = \DB::table('sample_point_mission')
        ->rightJoin('sample_point_record', 'sample_point_mission._id', '=','sample_point_record._pid')
        ->leftJoin('animal_name', 'sample_point_record.animal_name_id', '=','animal_name.tid::VARCHAR)')
        ->leftJoin('geographic_unit', 'sample_point_record.geography_unit_id', '=','geographic_unit.tid::VARCHAR');

$query->get();
```

error message ==>

```
SQLSTATE[42883]: Undefined function: 7 ERROR:  operator does not exist: character varying = integer
```

#### So I try to add the character it needs

```
$query = \DB::table('sample_point_mission')
        ->rightJoin('sample_point_record', 'sample_point_mission._id', '=','sample_point_record._pid')
        ->leftJoin('animal_name', 'sample_point_record.animal_name_id', '=','animal_name.tid::VARCHAR')
        ->leftJoin('geographic_unit', 'sample_point_record.geography_unit_id', '=','geographic_unit.tid::VARCHAR');

$query->get();
```

error message :

```
SQLSTATE[42703]: Undefined column: 7 ERROR:  column animal_name.tid::VARCHAR does not exist
```

Comment: You should use DB::raw('animal_name.tid::VARCHAR') in this instance as the query builder is assuming that the whole string is the column name. Using DB::raw will stop this from happening and allow the Postgres parser to understand it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can use raw Postgres SQL inside the a regular Laravel join function.  But, you can (and probably have to) use raw SQL with `DB::raw`.  Try this version:

```
$query = \DB::table('sample_point_mission')
        ->rightJoin('sample_point_record', 'sample_point_mission._id', '=','sample_point_record._pid')
        ->leftJoin('animal_name a', function($join) {
            $join->on(DB::raw("a.tid::VARCHAR"), DB::raw("="), DB::raw("sample_point_record.animal_name_i")) })
        ->leftJoin('geographic_unit g', function($join) {
            $join->on(DB::raw("g.tid::VARCHAR"), DB::raw("="), DB::raw("sample_point_record.geography_unit_id")) })

$query->get();
```